# How to map an optional URL parameter to params[:something] in Rails 3 "routes.rb"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following line in my `config/routes.rb`:

```
match "/assets/:id" => "assets#my_action"
```

I would like to change it so that both:

```
/aasets/id
```

and

```
/aasets/id/download
```

will be mapped to `assets#my_action`, and in case the URL ends with `/download` I'll have a sign inside `my_action` (say, `params[:something]` won't be `nil`).

How could I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply match both routes to the same controller.

```
match "/assets/:id" => "assets#my_action"
match "/assets/:id/:downloadparams" => "assets#my_action"
```

Your check for params[:downloadparams] will handle the rest.

EDIT: Oh "download" won't be a variable right? You could try something like

```
match "/assets/:id/:action" => "assets#my_action"
```

Check if `params[:action] == "download"` and ignore the parameter if it isn't.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in 1 line with :download as an optional parameter e.g.:

`match '/assets/:id(/:download)' => "assets#my_action"`

Then within your controller `params[:download]` could be used to check what was after the id in the URL, if anything.